# array <byte>^ in dictionary

Tags: c++-cli

I want to store an image data in an array byte into a dictionary.

```
int img_sz = img0->width * img0->height * img0->nChannels;

array <Byte>^ hh = gcnew array<Byte> (img_sz);

Marshal::Copy( (IntPtr)img->imageData, hh, 0, img_sz );

Dictionary<String^,array< Byte >^>^ myResult = gcnew Dictionary<String^,array< Byte >^>(); 

myResult->Add("OVERVIEW",hh);
```

Once it reaches the line myResult->Add("OVERVIEW",hh);

I am getting an :An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for duplicate keys.  `Dictionary::Add` can't be used to replace existing data.

You can see the error explained [in the documentation right here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx).  It specifically says

> ArgumentException               An element with the same key already exists in the Dictionary.

Comment: If you want to replace, `myResult["OVERVIEW"] = hh;` is the way to go.